# how to vertex parent an object to a quad face and not a tri?

Tags: objects, armature, vertices, faces, parent

theres a way to parent objects to vertex which only works two ways 1 vertex and 3 vertex, the problem is that my meshes usually consist of quads, **why is this**?

is there a way to parent to a face without the need of making tris?

just one vertex is not enough because i need my objects to rotate

Comment: you don't have to "make tris" (if you meant divide your quad), but yes you'll only be able to parent to 3 of the 4 vertices of your quad, as far as I know... so your object will rotate, but it will only follow 3 vertices

Comment: O.O I've been doing tris in so many meshes now, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: why are you doing tris? Is it to import into a game engine?

Comment: I may or may not have been doing this for no reason at all, i just didnt understand "select 3 vertices" didnt mean "select a tri" lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to "make tris" (if you meant divide your quad), you just need to parent to 3 of the 4 vertices of your quad. Your object will rotate, but it will only follow 3 vertices.